# New dataframe with two columns shows 0 rows after copying rows into one of the columns

Tags: r

What's wrong with: https://thepb.in/p/2RhK293yo50c4

```
PID <- character() 
  COVERAGE <- integer() 
  coverage <- data.frame(c(PID, COVERAGE)) 

coverage["PID"] <- laf[1:2,"PID"]; 

print(coverage);
```

gives 0 rows

```
[1] c.PID..COVERAGE. PID 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

whereas:

```
print(laf[1:2,"PID"])
```

gives 2 rows with data in PID

```
[1] "laf[1:2,\"PID\"]:" 
         PID 
1 4115077351 
2 4115077354
```

**Updated**

Further some errors are seen if I use:

```
coverage[["PID"]] <- laf[1:2,"PID"];
```

Error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PID", value = list(PID = c("4115077351",  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 0
```

**Updated per request in comments:**

This fixed width file is read into laf:

```
    4115077351        I29             
    4115077354        I27        27M5S
    411507735519480667E67194806    M5M
```

Also, seen in http://www.faststreamtech.com/stackexchange/stackoverflow/new-dataframe-with-two-columns-errors-with-0-rows/

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: laf does not contain any data in the example you have provided. Please update the example to make it reproducible.

Comment: You're trying to overwrite a subset that's empty, so nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
coverage[["PID"]] <- laf[1:2,"PID"]
```

You were assigning to a **subset** of *coverage* (through subset operator `[`). You should assign to a **member** (`[[` is the member access). These two function differently. When you need to assign to (or access) a member of a list, use `[[`. When you need to access a subset of a list, use `[`.
Assigning to a subset of a list is possible but should match the structure. Often you need `[[` for assigning tasks.